# Transactional Second Level Cache and Generated Identifier

Tags: spring, hibernate, jta, infinispan, atomikos

I have the following stack:

- Hibernate 3.6.9.Final
- Spring 3.1.1
- Atomikos 3.7.1
- Infinispan 4.2.1.FINAL
- MySQL

I have been writing a few tests to ensure that when a RuntimeException is thrown the current transaction is rolled back on the database but also on the transactional 2LC.

I have found found some odd results which I was hoping someone could explain.

If I use an @Entity annotated with @Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL) with a String @Id I see the results I expect when I assign the id and save the entity:

- When no exception is thrown the transaction is committed and the 2LC contains the entity, I confirmed this using:

`sessionFactory.getCache().containsEntity(MyEntity.class, myIdentifier)`

- If an exception is thrown neither the database or 2LC contain the entity.

However, if I repeat these tests using an `@Entity` which has a generated `@Id` (MySQL auto-incrementing long property) as shown:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private long id;
```

I find that the entity is never put in the 2LC, regardless of any exceptions thrown.

I have done some debugging and it seems to be down to the different code paths in `AbstractSaveEventListener#performSaveOrReplicate`. For an assigned `@Id` useIdentityColumn is false and so we instantiate and execute a EntityInsertAction which then puts the new entity in the 2LC.

Conversely, if the `@Id` is generated by MySQL we find that the useIdentityColumn is true and we instantiate and execute an EntityIdentityInsertAction. This contains commented out code regarding the 2LC as shown:

```
      //TODO: this bit actually has to be called after all cascades!
      //but since identity insert is called *synchronously*,
      //      instead of asynchronously as other actions, it isn't
      /*if ( persister.hasCache() && !persister.isCacheInvalidationRequired() ) {
         cacheEntry = new CacheEntry(object, persister, session);
         persister.getCache().insert(generatedId, cacheEntry);
      }*/
```

Is there any reason for this? Should the cache insert be done elsewhere? Is this a bug?

If anyone can shed any light on this difference and how this should work I would be very grateful.

I have posted this [question](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1015758&start=0) over on the Hibernate forums but haven't had much interest.

Comment: Not much interest here either! I might just raise it as an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I also think that this is quite a limitation for second-level cache usage so I created an [issue](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-7964) (HHH-7964). I also added a comment with a workaround, but this is only a proof of concept and should not be used for production as far as I can tell.

Comment: Great to hear that I'm not the only one to notice this! I'll keep an eye on your issue. I suspect that it's not going to be a high priority though since if you need it in the 2LC it'll be loaded (and cached) soon enough. It is interesting though.